# For primes $p,q$ one has $2p^2=q^2 + 1$. $p=5$ and $q=7 $ are solutions. Any others?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Given primes $p, q$ and $2p^2 = q^2 + 1$ one sees that $p = 5$ and $q = 7$ are solutions. Are they unique? Does this in any way relate to the fact that $7$ is the only solution to a prime $r$ in $r^3 + r^2 + r + 1 = n^2$?

Comment: Note that then $q^2-2p^2=-1$. See also [Pell's equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pell%27s_equation).

Answer (score 4):

At the risk of having Servaes downvote this answer as incoherent, from his comment I decided to look at the units in $\mathbb Z[\sqrt 2]$. Compute the sequence $(1 + \sqrt 2)^{2n + 1}$ to get units of norm $-1$ in the form $a + b \sqrt 2$, with $a$ and $b \in \mathbb Z$.

Then you're simply looking for $a$ and $b$ to both be prime. And so in that way from $7 + 5 \sqrt 2$ (corresponding to $n = 1$) I get $41 + 29 \sqrt 2$. The next one is $239 + 169 \sqrt 2$... oh, so close!

Answer (score 3):

How about $2\cdot 29^2=41^2+1?$  Ignoring the requirement of primes, the solutions recur with $p_{i+1}=3p_i+2q_i, q_{i+1}=4p_i+3q_i$.  You can compute those in a spreadsheet and look for pairs which are both prime.  My solution is the next one from yours.  I didn't find any more until Excel went into scientific notation.

Comment: The next ones are $(44560482149,\ 63018038201)$ and $(13558774610046711780701,\ 19175002942688032928599)$.

Comment: See [OEIS sequence A086397](https://oeis.org/A086397).